# flexbuilder 4.7, apache flex and ios7

Tags: apache, apache-flex, ios7

Ios7 appears to have broke flex. Here is what I did to resolve it:

Grey'd out icon and stuck in "installing" state on ipad.

- change folder in project and all references from (resources) to (res)

App stuck in portrait mode:

- upgrade to apache flex 4.11
- compile on Mac with ios7 sdk
- air ns 3.9

This took me alot of searching and trial and error.

Is this correct and how do I avoid this in the future (besides changing toolchain, please spare me)?
Anything else to watch out for?

Thx

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You say it is broken.  I have succesfully deployed Flex 4.6 apps to my iPhone 4 [running iOS7] without any issues.  So, what is broken?  Please be specific with code.  Which version of AIR are you using?  What folder did you change?  Is this a compile time problem or a run-time problem?

Comment: **Not a code issue, a deployment issue.**The two different issues are described above. Here is the original issue thread from adobe forums regarding the resources folder: http://forums.adobe.com/message/5722083#5722083.     Look above I'm using the apache flex SDK 4.11 (Air 3.9), Air 3.1 previously.

Comment: MXML:'<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
 <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
        <visible>true</visible>'Air 3.1, 4.6.0 flex previously
        <softKeyboardBehavior>pan</softKeyboardBehavior>
    </initialWindow>'

Comment: Also, I tried hard coding the LANDSCAPE behavior using the stage object as well.

Comment: I would say that no issues are described here in enough detail that would allow someone to answer.  Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the help section: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488904/flexbuilder-4-7-apache-flex-and-ios7# . Questions are best suited to be single focused; so if you have two separate problems; I suggest you post two separate questions.  I also recommend posting code samples and more details.  You can edit your question with the "Edit" Button underneath the tags to make this question more concise and/or add code samples.